# Magento 2 Setup Wizard Installation successfully but cannot access the Admin page

Tags: magento-2.1, admin, installation, cli

I've installed successfully the Magento-CE.2.1.7 via Setup Wizard installation in Ubuntu16.04 Apache2.4.18 PHP 7.0.18, but cannot access the Magento Admin in the web browser. I've tried command `a2enmod rewrite` or  `a2enmod access_compat`, but it does not solve the issue.

when I use the command  `php bin/magento cache:status` , get the errors below even I have enable openssl extension `extension=php_openssl.dll` and  `extension_dir = "ext"`  in the file `/etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini` :

```
The openssl extension is required for SSL/TLS protection but is not available. If you can not enable the openssl extension, you can disable this error, at your own risk, by setting the 'disable-tls' option to true.#0 /var/www/html/vendor/composer/composer/src/Composer/Factory.php(306): Composer\Factory::createRemoteFilesystem(Object(Composer\IO\BufferIO), Object(Composer\Config))
#1 /var/www/html/vendor/composer/composer/src/Composer/Factory.php(532): Composer\Factory->createComposer(Object(Composer\IO\BufferIO), Array, false)
#2 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Composer/ComposerFactory.php(47): Composer\Factory::create(Object(Composer\IO\BufferIO), '/var/www/html/...')
#3 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Composer/ComposerInformation.php(362): Magento\Framework\Composer\ComposerFactory->create()
#4 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Composer/ComposerInformation.php(375): Magento\Framework\Composer\ComposerInformation->getComposer()
#5 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Composer/ComposerInformation.php(242): Magento\Framework\Composer\ComposerInformation->getLocker()
#6 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/ProductMetadata.php(104): Magento\Framework\Composer\ComposerInformation->getSystemPackages()
#7 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/ProductMetadata.php(65): Magento\Framework\App\ProductMetadata->getSystemPackageVersion()
#8 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Console/Cli.php(81): Magento\Framework\App\ProductMetadata->getVersion()
#9 /var/www/html/bin/magento(22): Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->__construct('Magento CLI')
#10 {main}


Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Cli' not found in /var/www/html/bin/magento:31
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in /var/www/html/bin/magento on line 31
```

I have googled the issues , but no luck. Would you please help.

Answer (score 0):

Check

```
php -i | grep 'Configuration File'
```

to make sure you are editing the correct ini file.

Answer (score 0):

I run the command: `php -i | grep 'Configuration File'`
got the output:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /usr/local/lib
```

`Loaded Configuration File => (none)`

I've checked the path of configuration File (php.ini) Path: `/etc/php/7.0/apache2`

How I can change the configuration file path? Please advise. Thanks

Comment: I installed to versions of PHP. I reinstall PHP and the problem is solved. Thanks Paj for reminding me to check the Configuration File